# How to resolve Android Studio error: “Unable to determine activity name“?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in Android Studio, and when running my project, I came across the error "Unable to determine activity name". This happened right after configuring FireBase, but I don't know if it directly affected how it works.

Below is the detailed code of the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SmartHub"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FormCadastro"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FormLogin"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Inicio"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

How can I solve this problem?

I tried to re-enter the intent-filter, but it says unexpected. When I run the program, I would like it to start the "Splash Screen", which would change to ".FormLogin" afterward.

[image: Project componenets]

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the launcher activity:

```
<activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```